# Efficient way to keep state in reactive stream scan(), atomic, etc?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive-streams

Last time, I started implementing [bitbay.net](https://docs.bitbay.net/v1.0.1-en/reference#orderbook-3) subscription on orders.

The problem is that bitbay is returning a delta of orders, but I always want to keep the whole price depth (so I have to keep full price depth on my side and update it when some delta event occur):

```
bid    ask                                        bid     ask
----------                                        -----------
A      D  ------------>delta-event(removed=D)---> A       F
B      F                                          B       G
C      G                                          C
```

So I decided to use

```
Flux
   .from(eventsFromBitbay)
   .scan(FullPriceDepth.empty(), (pd, e) -> pd.update(e))
   .subscription(...)
```

My question is [Flux.scan(...)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#scan-A-java.util.function.BiFunction-) will be a good choice for that (in term of efficiency and thread safety)? I'm talking about millions of events in high spped system.

My alternative is to make some `Atomic...` and update it in `Flux.create(...).map(e -> atomicHere)` or is there something better?

Is `Flux.scan()` more efficient than `Atomic...`, why, why not?

Comment: Why just not keep it in a database, if you just want it inmemory use H2

Comment: 1. Blocking. 2 Transactions 3. Slow.. In memory, its better to use some kind of `Map`

Comment: 1. h2 is not blocking, or any database that has a r2dbc protocol driver, for instance postgres, mysql etc, or a nosql database like cassandra mongo etc. 2. transactions, thats not a reason and you dont need transactions if you dont want to use it. 3. Slow in compared to what, what benchmarks, what hardware, what loads.

Comment: 1. Network. 2. Update&Get 3. Compare to CAS data structures https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap

Comment: https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/#:~:text=Premature%20optimization%20is%20spending%20a,is%20credited%20to%20Donald%20Knuth.

Comment: What this link ^^^ has common with my question? I just asked is it ok to use `Flux.scan()` for keeping state when there are millions of events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"My question is Flux.scan(...) will be a good choice for that?"

Sure, why not? It's an obvious pattern, if you ask me. You have a class that holds information needed to process the flux. You should keep a couple things in mind though, mostly that the order of a flux is easy changed, for example by using `Flux::flatMap` instead of `Flux::flatMapSequential`, so you could easily get things in any order. Also, someone could put the flux on multiple threads so your `FullPriceDepth` properties might have to code for concurrency issues.